# Bootstrap dropdown menu in navbar: align icons horizontally instead of being vertically stacked

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, navbar, glyphicons

first time posting to StackOverflow and new developer, so please go easy on me :-)

I am using bootstrap to make a navbar on my site and am having an issue with the collapse dropdown menu.

[Desktop screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7zMJ.jpg)  *As this is my first post, images are not allowed to be embedded.*
As you can see, I have the logos nicely aligned on the right-hand side of the navbar.

My problems is that when viewed on a mobile screen/ smaller screen, the icons look messy when vertically stacked.[Smaller viewing port screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdpTp.jpg)

Ideally, I would like the icons to stay on one line in a way that does not jeopardize the overall style of how they look in full desktop mode.
Here is my HTML code, all using Bootstrap, no CSS have been altered: 
`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="600">
   <div class="container-fluid" id="navbarText">
   <div class="navbar-header">
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" id="zara"></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="nav-options">
                        <li><a href="#section1">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section2">Tools</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section3">Portfolio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section4">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>


                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="mailto:email@address"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a><span class="fa fa-phone"></span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/my-profile"><span class="fa fa-linkedin"></span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-github"></span></a></li>
                    </ul>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

`

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Try to use **list-Inline** class along with navbar-right and **list-inline-item** in li for horizontall alignment.
**For Reference:** https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/content/typography/#inline

Comment: Thank you for responding. I have just tried this and unfortunately it didn't work.